I closed the handle in resource monitor now my screen is black, no taskbar either! What can I do?
I wanted to change the name of a file, but Windows said it was still open. I looked it up in the resource monitor under associated handles and closed the handle with a right mouse click. Now my screen is black, and there is no taskbar. Even after restarting the laptop, it still doesn't change!
In the process of deleting the file, I closed explorer.exe.
How is this connected?

What was the file's exact name, and did you end up deleting it?

Laptops tend to sleep rather than shutdown.  Did you actually restart it?

"Even after restarting the laptop, it still doesn't change!" Try forcing full shutdown. If you cannot see the screen, then you might need to power off by holding the power button down for ~15 seconds. You might need to repeat that three times to enter SAFE mode, which forces a full reboot. Then just go back to normal Windows.

Press Ctrl+Alt+Del and select Task Manager, to open a task manager.
From here, go to menu File -> Start new task.
In the run dialog, type in explorer.exe and press OK.
This should give you your taskbar back.
This same trick can be used if you RDP into a computer. But instead, use CTRL-ALT-END.

A simplier way is to press Win+R then type "explorer" and press Enter.

@Amorphous I'm quite sure WIN+R is a shortcut that is activated once explorer is running. With explorer not running, WIN+R won't work, but Task Manager can still be accessed.
